# Cointegration in Time-Series

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I want to run a time series regression where I regress stock returns on each other. Clearly, the time series for stocks are typically not stationary, however, the returns are (I also tested that). I was wondering whether it is necessary to test the time series for cointegration since - as far as I know - cointegration is only a problem when the time series are not stationary.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer?

Answer (score 1):

You **should** test for cointegration on stock **prices**. It's typical for prices to be integrated and for returns to not be (as you've noticed), so you would not need to test for cointegration on stock **returns**.

If a cointegrating relationship exists between the prices, it can be interpreted as a specific portfolio whose value process is stationary. Such a portfolio is sometimes used in a strategy called *pairs trading* or *statistical arbitrage*.